# QTableView - samples

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

How to use `QTableView` in Nokia Qt SDK (for mobiles). I referred some of documents but still I am not clearing about the `QTableView`. Please any one suggest how to use the `QTableView`.

I want to show the `QTableView` with three columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the table data, you need to implement a model which will hold the data. If you don't require anything special, you can just subclass [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html).

Quoting the most important parts from the documentation:

> When subclassing QAbstractTableModel,
>   you must implement rowCount(),
>   columnCount(), and data().
>
> Editable models need to implement
>   setData(), and implement flags() to
>   return a value containing
>   Qt::ItemIsEditable.

You haven't specified where you get the data you are going to show in your table. That determines how you need to implement the required functions.

For even more simple model, use [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html) which already has a basic implementation for all required functions.

Comment: Hi, How to increase the table size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: got it. Using searchTable->resize(640,480);. It will increase the size.